# Converting multi language date time formats to "%Y-%m-%d"

Tags: python, python-dateutil

I'm scraping a references from the bottom of pages on wikipedia. These references contain an OpenUrl link which I can parse. Here's an example:

```
<span 
    title="ctx_ver=Z39.88-2004&amp;
    rft_val_fmt=info%3Aofi%2Ffmt%3Akev%3Amtx%3Ajournal&amp;
    rft.genre=unknown&amp;
    rft.jtitle=The+Tennessean&amp;
    rft.atitle=Belmont+University+awarded+final+2020+presidential+debate&amp;
    rft.date=2019-10-11&amp;
    rft.aulast=Tamburin&amp;
    rft.aufirst=Adam&amp;
    rft_id=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tennessean.com%2Fstory%2Fnews%2F2019%2F10%2F11%2Fbelmont-university-nashville-hosts-presidential-debate-2020%2F3941983002%2F&amp;
    rfr_id=info%3Asid%2Fen.wikipedia.org%3A2020+United+States+presidential+election" 

    class="Z3988">
</span>
```

I'm successfully obtaining the `rft.date` value. However the format of the value varies. I'm attempting to do two things:

1. 'Guess' the language and translate it (if possible)
2. Identify the format and reformat to `"%Y-%m-%d"`

Without the language issue I would be able to use [dateutil](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) (see half way down the page). However, the language issue stumps me completely.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to deal with the translation on examples like this?

```
0 "մայիսի 8, 2019"
1 "մայիսի 6, 2019"
2 "մայիսի 10, 2019"
3 "June 20, 2019"
4 "January 16, 2019"
5 "Aug 8, 2019"
6 "Aug 4, 2019"
...
12 "9 August 2019"
13 "8 May 2019"
14 "8 July 2020"
15 "8 July 2019"
16 "8 January 2020"
17 "8 de enero de 2020"
18 "7 tháng 8 năm 2019"
19 "7 May 2020"
...
33 "31 de diciembre de 2019"
...
40 "28 December 2019"
41 "28 de diciembre de 2019"
42 "27 de septiembre de 2019"
43 "26 November 2019"
44 "25 tháng 6 năm 2019"
45 "25 May 2019"
46 "25 March 2020"
47 "25 June 2019"
48 "24 June 2019"
49 "23 July 2019"
50 "22 tháng 7 năm 2019"
51 "22 July 2020"
52 "22 de abril de 2019"
53 "21 August 2019"
54 "2020-10-18"
55 "2020-09-21"
56 "2020-09-19"
57 "2020-09-16"
```

Comment: Scraping Wikipedia sounds wrong in the first place. Are the dates in regular form in the Wikipedia dump source?

Comment: @tripleee I agree on the scraping point. This personal project will move to a different solution for obtaining this information. For the moment it serves. What do you mean the dump source?

Comment: The usual and recommended way to get information from Wikipedia is through their API or by downloading their [dumps.](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/)

Comment: Ah yes, I already use the API to get title information. The references aren't part of the API. That's why the scraping. `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&origin=*&action=query&prop=extracts&explaintext=false&exintro&titles="+title`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) python library to achieve your goal.
I tried it locally and seems to work well.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

df = pd.read_csv('input_file.tsv', sep=' ', header=None, index_col=0)
df.columns = ['date']

df['translated'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: translator.translate(x).text)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                        date         translated                                             
0             մայիսի 8, 2019        May 8, 2019
1             մայիսի 6, 2019        May 6, 2019
2            մայիսի 10, 2019       May 10, 2019
3              June 20, 2019      June 20, 2019
4           January 16, 2019   January 16, 2019
5                Aug 8, 2019        Aug 8, 2019
6                Aug 4, 2019        Aug 4, 2019
12             9 August 2019      9 August 2019
13                8 May 2019         8 May 2019
14               8 July 2020        8 July 2020
15               8 July 2019        8 July 2019
16            8 January 2020     8 January 2020
17        8 de enero de 2020    January 8, 2020
18        7 tháng 8 năm 2019     August 7, 2019
19                7 May 2020         7 May 2020
33   31 de diciembre de 2019  December 31, 2019
40          28 December 2019   28 December 2019
41   28 de diciembre de 2019       Dec 28, 2019
42  27 de septiembre de 2019       Sep 27, 2019
43          26 November 2019   26 November 2019
44       25 tháng 6 năm 2019      June 25, 2019
45               25 May 2019        25 May 2019
46             25 March 2020      25 March 2020
47              25 June 2019       25 June 2019
48              24 June 2019       24 June 2019
49              23 July 2019       23 July 2019
50       22 tháng 7 năm 2019      July 22, 2019
51              22 July 2020       22 July 2020
52       22 de abril de 2019       Apr 22, 2019
53            21 August 2019     21 August 2019
54                2020-10-18         2020-10-18
55                2020-09-21         2020-09-21
56                2020-09-19         2020-09-19
57                2020-09-16         2020-09-16
```

Comment: This looks like the right solution for me but I'm having an issue. I've got the following code and get an error:  `publishdate = unquote_plus(rftValue)` `translator = Translator()` `publishdate = translator.translate(publishdate).text` the error is: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Comment: You need to make sure all the values in the `date` columns are valid non-empty strings. Translator will throw an error for invalid or empty-strings.

Comment: this is definitely a great answer. I just can't get this to work, even with populated strings. There appears to be some issue perhaps relating to networking which causes this to fall over. https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/234

Comment: I was able to run the code on your input and pasted the output above in the answer :)

Comment: Maybe you can paste your full dataframe in the question, and paste the full error with stack trace that you are getting

Comment: The rate limiting might be a concern of you are doing the translations on a very large set of strings. Is that the case?

Comment: Most likely. I'm figuring ways round this by reducing the number of calls to where necessary.

Comment: You could `sleep` for 5 seconds after every 1000 translations.

Comment: It's a good suggestion. There's not really going to be more than 1500 max. So I'm checking the format first. If it doesn't match only then translate.